# I Need Sharp Edge And Have Problems With Redirecting Edge Flow

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

After sub d I get no sharp edge but I think on that side must be sharp, can you help me with edge flow?
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please highlight precisely the part that should be sharp and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i add extra img with red circle and here is link of blender file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=AgB6Yp6s" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/AgB6Yp6s/)

Answer (score 3):

I think this topology works:

[image]

I beveled these edges and rearranged a bit all around:

[image]

Here is what it gives with the *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Previous shape:

[image]

Comment: THANKS MAN. i will try, what u think generally about my topology on that shape i am very beginner in 3d modeling

Comment: a bit messy but not too bad, but this part was difficult imho

Comment: I've corrected because I forgot the sharp angle that goes horizontally on the right